# Flow type refinement in events

Tags: javascript, flowtype, refinement-type

Well I have an event that happens "onchange" from a text input.

One of the obvious fields I would like to get during event handling is the new value of the input. A simple example is shown below:

```
onChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<>) => {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    const {something} = this.props;

    if (target && target.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
        something[fieldname] = target.value;
    }
};
```

This however chokes flow: flow complains that about:

> Error:(34, 47) Cannot get `target.value` because property `value` is missing in `EventTarget` [1].

Now how can I correctly refine this type? Apparently flow doesn't understand `hasOwnProperty`. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

The `SyntheticInputEvent` [generic](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/events/) requires type argument, you seems to missed it.

Smth, like this should make flow happy:

```
const onChange = (event: SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = event.currentTarget;
    console.log(target.value);
};
```